# Where can I find amsjpa, or is there a list of journal/publisher abbreviations available for amsrefs

Tags: amsrefs

The `amsrefs` package provides `\DefineJournal` and `\DefinePublisher` to define the abbreviations of journals and publishers.
I heard that there is a package called `amsjpa`, which contains \DefineJournal and \DefinePublisher statements for some most often mentioned ones.
However, I cannot find this package. It seems this package has been obsolete.

May I ask where can I find a collection of \DefineJournal and \DefinePublisher statements. Or, if there is no such collection, a list of journal/publisher abbreviations most often mentioned in AMS bibliographies.

Comment: I don't know of any package `amsjpa`, but MathSciNet (the online successor to Math, Reviews) at least used to have such a resource.  Information may be available at https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/help/resources but access depends on whether the institution you're located at is a subscriber.